# Try to compress Sha1 down in size, maybe a better option to make unique identifier

Tags: c#, java, php, python, uniqueidentifier

I have the following three pieces of information.  A group name, a group type, and group ranking.

As a quick example

"Mom's cats", "Cats", "Top10"

The example is way off from what I'm doing with this, but you get the basic idea.

The group name is a large selection of possible values (like around 20k) and the group type and group ranking are smaller amounts (like 10 each)

Trying to find a better way to come up with a short unique identifier for these group of things rather than having to use a `sha1` with a huge ugly URL.

Any better ideas?

Open to all language solutions, so just pinning a lot of programmers here since I can't think of a better tag to assign to this.

Thanks.

EDIT: One solution that I found elsewhere a while back stated about taking the last few characters in the `SHA-1` and converting them to a decimal value.  Not sure how reliable this idea is and the chance of collision.

EDIT2: Using mongoDB and storing this `sha1` value in the DB along with the members to make querying easy at the moment.  Trying to find an alternative solution to creating an `autoincrement` field in a seperate table/collection which means a lot more queries when running updating scripts.

Comment: Can you not just assign an incremental value to each group when it's first created? I.e. a database sequence number?

Comment: I suppose this is HTTP? If so, why not just make query parameters? A SHA1 is a hash (SHA stands for "Secure _Hash_ Algorithm"), therefore not a bijection; you cannot obtain back the original content from a SHA1 in any event

Comment: The SHA-1's are being stored in a database at the moment.  We are querying members based on this group Sha that they all share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python mappings you could use (grouptype, groupranking, groupname) as a dictionary key or you could reduce the size of the dictionaries by splitting something like a dictionary with a key of grouptype -> groupranking -> groupname.

For generating a unique url what is wrong with grouptype.rank.name or the same with / as a seperator - you could use the valid url type functions to replace invalid chars in each with %nn format.

You could use `urllib.quote('/'.join([baseurl, grouptype, groupranking, groupname])` to generate such a path or even `baseurl + urllib.urlencode({'grouptype':grouptype,'groupranking':groupranking,'groupname':groupname})` - the latter will result in the typical query format of baseurl?grouptype=Whatever&....

Comment: This is actually a great idea.  If nothing else ingenious comes up I will probably use this.  Thanks!